Xcode 16.0 beta AI feature confirmation
Ive installed Xcode 16 beta, and am wondering if there is a screen or setting I can use to confirm if the new AI feature pre-requisites are met and the service is active??
From talks it sounds like I have to be on MacOS 15 beta as well.
Thanks,
Chris

Go into Settings and click components. You should be able to see a Predictive Code Completion Model .
